# QTP not identifying a window in some playback

Tags: qtp

I am using descriptive programming. During playback, I want to check if the Windows print dialog does appear. Then I want to click the Cancel button in that dialog.

My problem: Sporadically QTP fails to identify the printing dialog, so clicking on the cancel button fails.

How can this possibly sometimes fail, sometimes succeed?

Comment: Show your code, describe the timing behind what happens in the script and in the GUI. Then, we might have a chance to help you. From what you´ve told so far I´d say you have a timing issue, or GUI object identification issues, or both.

Comment: Member for 11 months, zero rep, and this is your first question? What the..?

Comment: My code syntax given below:-
Set Window_EnterMeter  = browser_servicemanager.Window("regexpwndtitle:=Enter Meters.*")
Set dialog_Print    = Window_EnterMeter.Dialog("regexpwndtitle:=Print")
Set winbtn_CalcelPrint = dialog_Print.WinButton("regexpwndtitle:=Cancel")

Comment: fn chckprintpopupwndow()
{     ''''''''Navigating to that page
 call Absolutehighlight(Button_Action)
 call Absolutehighlight(Meter_Entry)
 call Absolutehighlight(PrintMeter_Opt2)
 AbsoluteClick(PrintMeter_Opt2)
 EnterMeters_Window.WebElement("html id:=ctl00_Save_BTN_C").Click

      '''''''By click on abve option window popup print option appears and QTP not identifying that window all times, so clicking on cancel button not doing so TC fails

 dialog_Print.Activate
 AbsoluteClick(winbtn_CalcelPrint)
 EnterMeters_Window.WebElement("html id:=ctl00_Cancel_BTN_C").Click

}

Comment: Duplicate of [UFT not identifying a window in some playback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075725/uft-not-identifying-a-window-in-some-playback) where you've actually pasted the code. This version of the question should be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As per as i see your code is refereing webelements of button for click. So what i would suggest is to avoid webelements and try not to use them.

If you could use the description.create for describing your object your work would be much easier.

Happy debugging.